Uber Ride integration in my app for token api giving invalid scope error
I was trying to integrate the Uber Ride API into our app. According to the documentation, we need to create an app on the Uber developer dashboard (https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/) and use the client_id and client_secret for the APIs.
I created the app and passed the scope as guests.trips for the token API, but we received an "invalid scope" error. Additionally, on the Access Token tab in the Uber developer dashboard for our app, we see the message: "Your application currently does not have access to Client Credentials scopes." as attached below.
Could Anybody please provide support on how we can use these Uber Ride APIs in our app? Are there any actions missed from our end to add the necessary scopes? Any documentation or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
I have gone through the documentation here https://developer.uber.com/docs/ but no luck also checked the doc here https://developer.uber.com/docs/guest-rides/introduction and also contacted Uber business support as there is no other support details available but they told to post the question on stackoverflow and now there is no further support details available so Please let me know how to go about.
